# How To Insert Data into UniData using UniObjects for .NET

Tags: .net, unidata, u2, uniobjects

I am working on inserting data into our UniData server from .net.

I have successfully updated an existing record using UniQuery by using the Modify statement. And according to the documentation, I can insert new data this way also:

> "UniQuery also provides the MODIFY command, which enables you to **enter** or modify data in a UniData file." - Using UniQuery: pg 1-2

I can't get manage to insert new records this way, though.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UniData, you cannot programmatically insert new records using UniQuery.

At ECL you can manually create records using `UNIENTRY` if the appropriate dictionary items have been defined or you can use `ED` or `AE` to create them. All 3 of these require the user to manually enter data however.

To create new records programmatically you should create a subroutine specifically used for the task and call this via UniObjects.NET